# gawk error on windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command, gawk

I am trying to run a perl script as shown below but am met with error as explained here.

$filenames = `ls -l newdir|grep smlist|gawk -F" " '{ print \$8 }'`;

Here is the error I get:

The system cannot find the path specified.
gawk: '{
gawk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Please help out with possible solutions.

Comment: Solved: ls -l newdir|grep smlist|gawk -F" " "{ print \$8 }"

Answer (score 0):

`gawk`, `grep` and `ls` are not Windows native commands.

To use them in the way you have shown, you need them all installed in the current folder or in folders that are added to the PATH